# when i click to recyclarview iteam it should hide from my recyclarview

Tags: mysql, android-studio, android-recyclerview, show-hide, disable

I want to make that people visit my website one time one site per person.
i am using mysql database for my data base .
i want to make when the user click on the visit button the he will redirect to the site **(i had configured).**
and that persion not able to go same site again. the button should show visited and its should be disable or hide form recyclar view **(How to do,I want this).**

**My adapter class:**

```
    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageViewHOlder> {
    
        private Context context;
        private List<ModelImage> imageList;
    
    
        public MyAdapter(Context context, List<ModelImage> imageList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.imageList = imageList;
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ImageViewHOlder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout_item,parent,false);
            return new ImageViewHOlder(view);
    
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHOlder holder, final int position) {
    
    
            holder.title.setText(imageList.get(position).getPost_title());
            holder.date.setText("Uploaded on: "+imageList.get(position).getDate());
            Glide.with(context).load(imageList.get(position).getFeatured_image()).into(holder.imageView);
            holder.check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String url = imageList.get(position).getPost_slug();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            });
    
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return imageList.size();
        }
    } 
class ImageViewHOlder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView title,date;
        Button check;
        public ImageViewHOlder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
    
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            check = itemView.findViewById(R.id.check);
        }
    
    }
```

**my custom layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/check"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="Visit"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/check"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/check"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I would suggest to add one more column with flag i.e. status with Boolean values as visited = 1 & not_visited= 0, once user click on visit update database status column with visited value and notify dataset changed. Also based on this flag add logic to hide/show/disable in Recyclerview Adapter.

Comment: can you explain, i understand what are you saying but i dont know how to implement please guide.